# Reallocating char** array in c (Seg fault core dumped)

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, realloc, coredump

I m reallocating a `char**` array with every entry and while compiling comes back clean, only the first entry is stored and I get Segmentation fault (core dumped) always when i try to register a 4th entry.

Here is the relevant code in main.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int i,sizea,sizeb,choice,letters,check,mistakes,count;
    char C[26][2];
    char **A,**B,a;

    A=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    *A=(char*)malloc((MAX_CHAR+1)*sizeof(char));

    sizea=1;
    build(&A,&sizea);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the implementation of the method in mylib.c:

```
void build(char ***A, int *sizea)
{
    *A=(char**)realloc(*A,(*sizea) * sizeof(char*));
    *A[*sizea-1]=(char*)malloc((MAX_CHAR+1)*sizeof(char));

    printf("Give word :");
    scanf("%s",(*A[*sizea-1]));

    (*sizea)++;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

edit: similar problems in this method that werent fixed by doing the same thing

```
void find(char **A, char ***B, int letters,int sizea, int *sizeb){

int i,j,k,dummy;
char a='a';

  for(i=0;i<(sizea-1);i++){
    printf("here\n");
      if(A[i][letters]=='\0'){
      *B=(char**)realloc(*B,(*sizeb+1) * sizeof(char*));
      (*B)[*sizeb]=(char*)malloc((letters+1)*sizeof(char));
      (*B)[*sizeb-1]=A[i];
      *sizeb++;
      printf("%s\n", (*B)[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: General nitpicks: `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition, so multiplying by it is pointless. Don't cast the return value of `malloc`. Don't read with `scanf` without specifying a maximum width. Prefer `array = malloc(count * sizeof(*array))` instead of having `sizeof(element_type)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
scanf("%s",(*A[*sizea-1]));
```

The array index operator `[]` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.  So the above parses as:

```
scanf("%s",(*(A[*sizea-1])));
```

What you want is:

```
scanf("%s",((*A)[*sizea-1]));
```

Similarly, this:

```
*A[*sizea-1]=(char*)malloc((MAX_CHAR+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Should be:

```
(*A)[*sizea-1]=(char*)malloc((MAX_CHAR+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: What you said fixed the problem, and i assumed it wuld be the solution to a similar one in another method but its not the case. Could you take a look at the edit?